# Subsetting, reordering, and assigning according to a variable with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I was wondering what's the "recommended" way of assigning values to subsets of data frame according to the dplyr philosophy. This is probably best illustrated by an example. Say I have a data frame (named `df`):

```
V1 V2
 a  1
 b  2
 c  3
```

I would like to change the value of `V2` to `2` when `V1` is `"a"`, and to `1` when `V1` is `"c"`. In R base language, this is often achieved by `rownames`:

```
rownames(df) <- df$V1
df[c("a", "c"), ]$V2 <- c(2, 1)
```

After some searching, the most concise solution I could come up with using the dplyr language is

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(V2 = recode(V1, "a" = 2, "c" = 1) %>% 
       ifelse(V1 %in% c("a", "c"), ., V2))
```

But it felt clumsy. Am I missing something? What is the best way to change values of parts of a data frame using dplyr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `case_when`.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(V2 = case_when(
    V1 %in% "a"    ~ 2L,
    V1 %in% "c"    ~ 1L,
    TRUE           ~ V2
  ))
df2
#   V1 V2
# 1  a  2
# 2  b  2
# 3  c  1
```

**DATA**

```
df<- read.table(text = "V1 V2
 a  1
 b  2
 c  3",
                header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```